# Password Hashing through BCrypt in Android and iOS

Tags: android, spring

I am hashing the password through BCrypt before sending it to server. My question is how the server will validate the hash password for authentication. Because every time different hash generated for the same password in Android/iOS. Server application is in Spring.

Comment: Ideally, your server creates an hash for the password with a pre-determined 'key' and 'salt' so that when user logs in again, it can create the hash using the same 'key' and 'salt' to check whether it matches. And the app sends the password in plain-text or a reversible encryption to the server via HTTPS. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110415/is-it-ok-to-send-plain-text-password-over-https
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side?rq=1

Comment: As for your question, if you want to hash your password on the client side, you must have pre-determined 'key' and 'salt' in your app. This must never change, otherwise hash will be different. Now, you'll need to store this 'key' and 'salt' in your APK which is not recommended since it's easy to reverse engineer an APK.

Comment: Thank you sharing your thought. Let's see if we get any another comment/answer.

Comment: explain in details your authentication scheme; Bcrypt is resulting in different hashes probably because you're using different salt or/and iteration numbers each time;

Comment: Instead of sending plain text, want to send hash of password to the server so that can prevent any men in middle attack. I know can use SSL pinning but that is another approach. Event I tried same iteration/round produced different salt.

Comment: "Event I tried same iteration/round produced different salt"-> that's probably because you are using a random generator to yield a salt for you; if you pass the same password_string, iteration_number and salt to Bcrypt it must produce the same hash every time;